# Remove <script> with JS

Tags: javascript

I would like to **remove everything inside** of an `HTML-section`, using JS, but there are `<script>`-tags inside of the section and **JS does not remove them**, why and how can I do this?

Code:

```js
document.querySelector(".desktop_only").remove();
```

```html
<section class="desktop_only">
  The JS removes this text.
  <script> alert("It does not remove the alert, why?"); </script>
</section>
```

Comment: _“It does not remove the alert, why?”_ - because the alert has already happened, before you remove code even runs. Removing the script element after it has already been executed, does not make whatever it did, become undone again.

Comment: @CBroe Ah, ok… Thank You!

Comment: I'm guessing that the `alert()` has already been put in the event queue when the `remove()` command runs. After that, the `remove()` code runs. And then finally the event queue is processed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is HTML scripts are usually run first, then come any included scripts at the bottom of the HTML, so the alert script is probably removed *after* it already ran. It would be helpful if you added a codepen.io link!